# Convert variables to ASCII in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ascii

In Rails (Ruby 1.9+), you can call `?a.ord` to get the ascii character for "a".

How can you do the same thing for a variable that contains a single character?

```
myvar = "a"
?myvar.ord      # fails
?(myvar).ord    # fails
?[myvar].ord    # fails
?{myvar}.ord    # fails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?a.ord` is equivalent to this:

```
s = ?a
s.ord
```

So all you need to do is call the [`String#ord`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-ord) method on your string:

```
myvar.ord
```

Keep in mind that `?a` is the same as `'a'`, it is just a (rather strange) shorthand for creating single character strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
myvar = "a"
myvar.ord # => 97
```

String#ord is a method that returns the codepoint of the first character of the receiver string, so you can just call it on a variable that contains a string object.

`?a` is a way of writing a string that represents the character a.

Answer (score 0):

`"a".ord` You can check out the ruby docs API to verify http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html